# Should I include both GZ and XML sitemaps in robots.txt?

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap

My sitemap generator has created a *sitemap.xml* and *sitemap.xml.gz* file. Should I include just the *.gz* file in the *robots.txt* or both?

And does it do any harm to submit both sitemaps to Google et al?

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, a lot of sites nowadays don't even use robots.txt all together. Adding the site map to WMT is more than enough.

Comment: If both contain the same information, why submit both? What would be the point in that? Just submit one. The gz version should be a compressed version of the text sitemap. The gz file should download faster. Please understand that for most sites, a sitemap is nearly entirely useless. Sites that recommend that you submit a sitemap are completely wrong in suggesting it wholesale. Only sites that cannot be crawled, are extremely large, have a paywall or login should worry about a sitemap. Otherwise, it is a waste of effort, time, and bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

As Closetnoc mentioned in his comment, GZ is just a compressed version of your text sitemap. So my answer to your question

> Should I include just the .gz file in the robots.txt or both?

There is no point in submitting both *sitemap.xml* as well as *sitemap.xml.gz*. [Most of the search engine bots can read the compressed content](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/49335/28169). So if you are submitting *sitemap.xml* it's enough or *sitemap.xml.gz* is enough.

> does it do any harm to submit both sitemaps to Google

I don't find any valuable source to say that Google will harm you in this case also from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) page you can see that you will not be penalized by Google.

> Google - Webmaster Support on Sitemaps: "Google doesn't guarantee that
>   we'll crawl or index all of your URLs. However, we use the data in
>   your Sitemap to learn about your site's structure, which will allow us
>   to improve our crawler schedule and do a better job crawling your site
>   in the future. In most cases, webmasters will benefit from Sitemap
>   submission, and in no case will you be penalized for it."

Comment: Answering "no" to an either/or question when the first part is correct doesn't make sense.